# JS still refers to class that has been removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a element which as a `.collapsed` class, after clicking this a jQuery function removes this class and add `.expanded`.

When clicking on the element once the `.collapsed` has been removed it still runs the function I've created.

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapsed">
Some content that will be changed
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function expandItem() {
            $(this).addClass("expanded");
            $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
        return false;
    }

    $('.collapsed').click(expandItem);

});
```

Comment: use `$(document).ready(function() { $('.collapsed').click(expandItem); });`

Comment: why would the code not run? The `$('.collapsed').click(expandItem);` line means "find me all items that have class 'collapsed', and give them this click handler: ...". Whether or not you then remove the class at some later point has zero effect on the fact that you bound that click handler earlier.

Comment: @TamilSelvan I did actually have the document ready line, I just didn't add it to the code above. Please excuse my brevity I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), because otherwise the selector is evaluated only once when the code `$('.collapsed').click(expandItem);` is executed changes made after that to the dom structure will not affect the already added handlers.

When you use event delegation, the passed selector is lazily evaluated when the event occurs, thus will react to changes made after the registration.

```
function expandItem() {
    $(this).addClass("expanded");
    $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
    return false;
}

$(document).on('click', '.collapsed', expandItem);
```